# What's difference between version-current and post-release updates for Nvidia drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between the nvidia-current, and nvidia-current-updates packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66548/whats-the-difference-between-the-nvidia-current-and-nvidia-current-updates-pac)

What's difference between version-current and post-release updates for Nvidia drivers? Can you say which version is installed by selection of those choices? Which one is newer?