# What's difference between using nvidia-current, nvidia-current-updates, 310.19.run, bumblebee and noveau?

Tags: drivers, graphics

I use Geforce 630M 2GB.

I want to know which driver I should use.

Which one is recommended?

What's their advantage and disadvantages?

And what's the correct way to install those driver?

It trouble me when install one driver should remove other driver.

Thank you~

Comment: `bumblebee` is not a driver. It is a service (daemon) application that enable us to use highend GPU in optimus enabled laptop. Follow bumblebee install guide for safe install. Rest of the answer can be found here - http://askubuntu.com/q/66548/35775 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: How to use command to check my laptop use optimus or not? Thank you~

Comment: `630m` should be optimus. Use `lspci | grep VGA`, it should list two graphics card.